# json array is not recognized as an array

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, flask

I am trying to fetch data from an api to use in my react app. My app cannot access the data because it is not in the correct format. The expected format is a json array, however the data being fetched does in fact appear to be in the anticipated format. I have several console logs in my code to determine whether or not the data being received is an array, and some are saying it is an array, while others are saying it is not an array. Why is the data not being recognized throughout my component as a json array? The following is my react component:
'''

```
interface DataItem {
 'Estimate Quality': number;
 'Velocity (km/s)': number;
 'Radius (m)': number;
 'Mass (kg)': number;
 'Charge (C)': number;
 'Time': number;
 'Trace Number': number;
}

const useFetchedArrays = () => {
  const [EstimateQualities, setEstimateQualities] = useState<number[]>([]);
  const [Velocities, setVelocities] = useState<number[]>([]);
  const [radii, setRadii] = useState<number[]>([]);
  const [masses, setMasses] = useState<number[]>([]);
  const [charges, setCharges] = useState<number[]>([]);
  const [times, setTimes] = useState<number[]>([]);
  const [traceNumbers, setTraceNumbers] = useState<number[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
  // Fetch the JSON data from test.json
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/data?limit=${100}')
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then((data) => {
    // Explicitly parse the JSON data
       const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);

       console.log('API Response:', parsedData);

    // Check the type and structure of the parsed data
    if (typeof parsedData === 'object') {
      if (Array.isArray(parsedData)) {
        console.log('Data is an array:', parsedData);
      } else {
        console.log('Data is an object:', parsedData);
      }
    } else {
      console.error('Unexpected data format:', parsedData);
    }

      if (Array.isArray(data)) {
        console.log('Data is an array:', data);
        // Extract data and update state
        const qualities: number[] = [];
        const velocities: number[] = [];
        const radius: number[] = [];
        const mass: number[] = [];
        const charge: number[] = [];
        const time: number[] = [];
        const traceNumber: number[] = [];

        data.forEach(item => {
          qualities.push(item['Estimate Quality']);
          velocities.push(item['Velocity (km/s)']);
          radius.push(item['Radius (m)']);
          mass.push(item['Mass (kg)']);
          charge.push(item['Charge (C)']);
          time.push(item['Time']);
          traceNumber.push(item['Trace Number']);
        });

        setEstimateQualities(qualities);
        setVelocities(velocities);
        setRadii(radius);
        setMasses(mass);
        setCharges(charge);
        setTimes(time);
        setTraceNumbers(traceNumber);

        console.log('Updated state:', EstimateQualities);
      } else {
        console.error('Data is not an array:', data);
      }
  })
  .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching data:', error));
 }, []); // Empty dependency array ensures useEffect runs once on component mount

return {
  EstimateQualities,
  Velocities,
  radii,
  masses,
  charges,
  times,
  traceNumbers,
};
};

export default useFetchedArrays;
```

'''

The following is my flask API:

'''

```
# || Connect to the server
db_connection_str = '...'
db_connection = create_engine(db_connection_str)

app = Flask(__name__)

CORS(app)


@app.route('/api/data', methods=['GET'])
def get_data():
   print("********RETRIEVING  DATA**********")
   limit = request.args.get('limit', default=100, type=int)
   query = f"select estimate_quality, integer_timestamp, velocity, mass, charge, 
   radius from dust_event where mass != -1 order by integer_timestamp desc limit 
   {limit};"
awsdf = pd.read_sql(query, con=db_connection)

print(f"****** QUERY = {query}******")

awsdf.columns = ["Estimate Quality", "Time", "Velocity (km/s)", "Mass (kg)", "Charge (C)", "Radius (m)"]
awsdf["Velocity (km/s)"] /= 1000.0
awsdf = awsdf.sort_values(by=["Time"], ascending=True)

awsdf["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(awsdf['Time'], unit='ms')
awsdf["Time"] = awsdf["Time"].dt.tz_localize('utc').dt.tz_convert('US/Mountain')
awsdf["Time"] = awsdf["Time"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

awsdf['Trace Number'] = range(1, len(awsdf) + 1)

return jsonify(awsdf.to_json(orient='records'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(port=5000)
  #app.run(debug=True)
```

'''

The following are my console logs:

' API Response: (100) [{…}, {…}, ...] ',
'Data is an array: (100) [{…}, {…}, ...]',
'Data is not an array: [{"Estimate Quality":2,"Time":"2023-11-03 15:14:02.902000","Velocity (km/s)":8.28797,"Mass (kg)":1.28268e-17,"Charge (C)":2.00513e-16,"Radius (m)":0.000000073,"Trace Number":1},{"Estimate Quality":2,"Time":"2023-11-03 15:14:08.041000","Velocity (km/s)":5.5143,"Mass (kg)":2.38666e-16,"Charge (C)":0.0,"Radius (m)":0.0000001934,"Trace Number":2}, ...]',
'populateData.tsx:76 Error fetching data: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON'